# Java Reactor - conditional stream execution

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I was wondering how to create "logical stream" using Reactor.

Lets assume that I want to implement following scenario:

As input I have object to save in database. As output I would like to get Mono representing execution message.

- **Option 1:**  if object to save has all fields filled then I perform additionall operations, save it to database and finally return "`Success`" message
- **Option 2:** if object to save has at least one field not filled I return "`Error`"

I have created such code:

```
Mono<String> message = Mono.just(new User("Bob the Reactor master")) // user with name = can be saved
    .flatMap(user -> {
        if(user.getName() != null && user.getName().length() > 1){
            // Perform additional operations e.g. user.setCreatedDate(new Date())
            // Save to repository e.g. repository.save(user)
            return Mono.just("Success!");
        }
        else{
            return Mono.just("Error!");
        }
    })
    .doOnNext(System.out::println); // print stream result

message.subscribe();
```

Is this code 100% reactive (has all its benefits)? If no then what it will look like?

Comment: As you don't have any asynchronous parts, you don't really need reactor here.

Comment: Lets assume that this code is located in microservice POST handler.

Comment: There is no need for an `else` clause in this case.

Comment: @Wicia would it not be better to check this as a \@Valid condition on the handler?

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on your commented repository.

- Repository is non-blocking and returns Mono or Flux

  You should subscribe it then return Success Mono. In your if statement:

  ```
  return repository.save(user).then(Mono.just("Success!"));
  ```
- Repository is blocking

  You should make your repository call non-blocking moving its execution to separate thread. Reactor way is to wrap it with Mono and subscribe on elastic scheduler or your custom scheduler.

  ```
  Mono<String> message = Mono.just(new User("Bob the Reactor master"))
          .filter(user -> user.getName() != null && user.getName().length() > 1)
          .map(user -> user) // Perform additional operations e.g. user.setCreatedDate(new Date())
          .flatMap(user -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> repository.save(user))
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                  .then(Mono.just("Success!")))
          .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("Error!"));
  ```